# Asp.Net Core policies is running all requirements even if first ones are not succeeded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, policies

I'm creating custom policies for a web api. I assumed that requiring a authenticated user in a policy would prevent other requirements to be ran. I know that adding multiple requirements forces them all the be passed so essentially I see multiple requirements to have a `&&` relationship, but they seem to be more of a `&` relationship.

```
var requireUser = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                            .RequireClaim("USER_ID")
                            .Build();

options.DefaultPolicy = requireUser;

options.AddPolicy("RequireSomeDatabaseProperty",
                    p => p.Combine(requireUser)
                        .AddRequirements(new SomeDatabasePropertyRequirement));
```

I'm finding that the database call will be made. Since it would be based on the `USER_ID` claim I would probably have to put a guard there anyways, making the `requireUser` policy totally mute.

Is this the intended usage, or is something else wrong here. Does `combine()` not work like I think it works?

Is there anyway for me to just end the Authorization process on require user if the user isn't authenticated?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4656

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior as stated in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#what-should-a-handler-return)

But you have a way to change that behavior by setting `InvokeHandlersAfterFailure` to False